# Shadows doesn't disappear

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I made an endless runner game where the horse runs in a canyon. So i noticed that in the walls makes shadows on theirselves so i wanted to remove it beacuse it's ugly. So my problem comes here, how can i remove that shadow even if i disabled the shadow casting from the mesh renderer of that walls? I also tried to place a light point near the walls but it still don't work. How can i resolve this. I attach a photo so you can understand what i am talking about.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLTSa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Those are most likely just objects interacting with a directional light in the scene. Instead of shadows, those are just sides of objects that as less illuminated.

I can throw in two potential solutions:

### Solution1:

Go to `Window->Rendering->Lighting`, select `Environment`, change the `Environment Lighting` `Source` value and modify the color values to your liking.
[image]

### Solution2:

Add a material which changes how the objects interact with lighting. One option could be to just add a standard material with some emission.
[image]